# Finding duplicate rows in mysql table from same ip

Tags: mysql

in my database I log the users ip every time they register in users table, I wanted to know if I can use a query to select every user that has registered more than once? (example: rows with the same column value)

Comment: Yes, you can do that. However, using ip address to detect duplicate registrations is a bad idea. Multiple users may have the same ip address at the same time, plus dynamic ip addresses can be asdigned to multiple users after each other.

Comment: Your title and body suggest two different things that you need.  You should really edit the question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score -2):

I think your solution could look more or less like this:

```
select count(*) as numberofrows, 
userid  
from users 
group by ip
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Did you just copied my answer?

Comment: In fact i answered before you. Anyway, thanks for rating down.

Comment: Look at the time stamp, you are 7 min ago and I'm 12 . Are you blind?

Comment: You are right. I started answering before any other answer has been posted. Maybe our answers are similar because there are not too many way of solving this problem. I just tried to help.